# Issue with output of Powershell function

Tags: function, powershell

I'm writing a function and observing some unusual behavior with the output.

This is the code:

```
Function Get-CompInfo
{
    [Cmdletbinding()]
    PARAM 
    (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [Alias('Comp', 'Host')]
        [string[]]$computername
    )


    Begin
    {

    }
    Process
    {
        if ($computername -eq $Null) {
                $computername=$env:computername
                $VerboseOut="No computer specified. Running against local computer $computername :"
        }
            Else {
                $VerboseOut="Getting information for computer $computername :"
        }
        Write-Verbose $VerboseOut
        $CompInfo=Get-WmiObject Win32_Computersystem -computername $computername 
        $OSInfo=Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -computername $computername 
                $Properties = [ordered]@{
                'Input'=$computername
                'SystemName'=$CompInfo.Name
                'Manufacturer'=$CompInfo.Manufacturer
                'Model'=$CompInfo.Model
                'PhysicalMemory'=$CompInfo.TotalPhysicalMemory
                'LogicalProcessors'=$CompInfo.NumberOfLogicalProcessors
                'OSCaption'=$OSInfo.Caption
                'OSArchitecture'=$OSInfo.OSArchitecture
                'ServicePackMajorVersion'=$OSInfo.ServicePackMajorVersion}

        # Output Information
        $obj=New-Object -TypeName PSobject -Property $Properties
        write-output $obj 

    }
    End
    {

    }
}
```

When passing parameters from the pipline:

**"karuma", "localhost" | Get-CompInfo**

```
Input                   : {karuma}
SystemName              : KARUMA
Manufacturer            : Hewlett-Packard
Model                   : h9-1400a
PhysicalMemory          : 17115000832
LogicalProcessors       : 8
OSCaption               : Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
OSArchitecture          : 64-bit
ServicePackMajorVersion : 0

Input                   : {localhost}
SystemName              : KARUMA
Manufacturer            : Hewlett-Packard
Model                   : h9-1400a
PhysicalMemory          : 17115000832
LogicalProcessors       : 8
OSCaption               : Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
OSArchitecture          : 64-bit
ServicePackMajorVersion : 0
```

I get the same kind of output when I pass a text file with a list of computer names.

When specifying multiple host names something different:

**Get-CompInfo -computername localhost, karuma**

```
Input                   : {localhost, karuma}
SystemName              : {KARUMA, KARUMA}
Manufacturer            : {Hewlett-Packard, Hewlett-Packard}
Model                   : {h9-1400a, h9-1400a}
PhysicalMemory          : {17115000832, 17115000832}
LogicalProcessors       : {8, 8}
OSCaption               : {Microsoft Windows 10 Pro, Microsoft Windows 10 Pro}
OSArchitecture          : {64-bit, 64-bit}
ServicePackMajorVersion : {0, 0}
```

I'm expecting to see table output when passing multiple values as would by seen by piping to format-table.

Any help on what I need to change to get the output as desired would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the way you have your function setup... when using the pipeline the PROCESS block will be run once for each object in the pipeline - the $computername param will only contain a single object at a time in this situation.

When you specify two computers in $computername param, you are changing the way the entire function is running as it contains two objects.

It's easy to fix by wrapping your function in a Foreach like so:

```
Function Get-CompInfo
{
    [Cmdletbinding()]
    PARAM 
    (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [Alias('Comp', 'Host')]
        [string[]]$computername
    )

    Begin {}
    Process
    {
        Foreach ($computer in $computername) {
            if ($computer -eq $Null) {
                    $computer=$env:computername
                    $VerboseOut="No computer specified. Running against local computer $computer :"
            }
                Else {
                    $VerboseOut="Getting information for computer $computer :"
            }
            Write-Verbose $VerboseOut
            $CompInfo=Get-WmiObject Win32_Computersystem -computername $computer 
            $OSInfo=Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -computername $computer 
                    $Properties = [ordered]@{
                    'Input'=$computer
                    'SystemName'=$CompInfo.Name
                    'Manufacturer'=$CompInfo.Manufacturer
                    'Model'=$CompInfo.Model
                    'PhysicalMemory'=$CompInfo.TotalPhysicalMemory
                    'LogicalProcessors'=$CompInfo.NumberOfLogicalProcessors
                    'OSCaption'=$OSInfo.Caption
                    'OSArchitecture'=$OSInfo.OSArchitecture
                    'ServicePackMajorVersion'=$OSInfo.ServicePackMajorVersion}

            # Output Information
            $obj=New-Object -TypeName PSobject -Property $Properties
            write-output $obj 
        }
    }
    End {}
}
```

Comment: Dom Jones has a great article that explains this behavious with nice examples: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh413265.aspx

Comment: Hey James, thanks heaps!

Can't believe I overlooked that but got it working and was able to pass out properties with select etc.

That article looks interesting too, will check it out!